# How to set the same values for all drop dpwn lists in a gridview by a setiting a value in the very first drop down list of the gridview?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid-view which is data bound and it consists of a drop down list, and a check box in every row. I would want to provide an option where in the user clicks a select all check box in the header and selects a value from the drop down list in the first row and all the subsequent drop down lists must automatically populate with the same value as the first drop down list. 
Any links/suggestions please?

Regards, 
Laura

The aspx code for the grid view:

```
        >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>

            <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="allchk" runat="server" Text="All" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:CheckBox ID="selectchk" runat="server" />

            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TR. ID">

            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="namelbl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

The Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function SelectAll(id)
        {
            //get reference of GridView control
            var grid = document.getElementById("<%= GridView1.ClientID %>");
            //variable to contain the cell of the grid
            var cell;

            if (grid.rows.length > 0)
            {
                //loop starts from 1. rows[0] points to the header.
                for (i=1; i<grid.rows.length; i++)
                {
                    //get the reference of first column
                    cell = grid.rows[i].cells[0];

                    //loop according to the number of childNodes in the cell
                    for (j=0; j<cell.childNodes.length; j++)
                    {           
                        //if childNode type is CheckBox                 
                        if (cell.childNodes[j].type =="checkbox")
                        {
                        //assign the status of the Select All checkbox to the cell checkbox within the grid
                            cell.childNodes[j].checked = document.getElementById(id).checked;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

And the code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

           //header select all function
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("allchk")).Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:SelectAll('" +
                    ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("allchk")).ClientID + "')");


            }

            }
```

After I have added a drop down list in all the rows, I would like to provide an option if the user selects the checkbox in header, and sets the value in the first drop down list, I want the same respective value to be populated in the other drop down list.

Comment: What you did? Can you show your code here?

Comment: @RameshRajendran I'm sorry, I have no clue of how to do anything about it. But I can add the code which is in present state. I'll do it write away

Comment: Providing some code could be much helpul

Comment: We need your code to be able to help.

Comment: Guys, I suggest not to be so ugly to the OP on their very first question. This is the case. @Laura, On Stackoverflow there are clear rules, please read the help page on how to ask a question. In short, if you ask for help on code we expect to see the code and to get an explanation about the specific problem you are experiencing. So try to add these information to your question. This will avoid negative score to your rep.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I have included the basic codes.

Comment: To be more specific, I'm looking for a better solution for this question - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977118/set-value-of-dropdown-lists-in-gridview-with-javascript?rq=1]